# docker service loadbalancing failed

Tags: load-balancing, docker-swarm, virtual-ip-address

I have a 2 docker services, service_1 and service_2. Each with one container.
Both of them have overlay network so I can use the swarm DNS resolving,
service_1 is accessing service_2 using the service name as DNS name.

However, after 20+ hours of communication, service_1 trying to access service_2:

`wget service_2`

But it gets an error:

```
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.0.0.21): Address not available
```

The real service_2 container IP is 10.0.0.22.
The service VirtualIP is 10.0.0.21.

The network inspect shows the range "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.22/24" for service_2.

If I run from service_1 the following command (using the real service_2 container IP):

```
wget 10.0.0.22
```

I got the right response.

So to conclude it's seems some problem with VirtualIP loadbalancing.
Did anyone encounter this problem too?